# EXCEL: Searching a table of data with two criteria and outputting the rows to a new table

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a table of data (Data!$A$8004:$F$10430) within an excel sheet which I need to search for all of the rows that contain the date displayed in cell: Data!Q27 (e.g may-2017) in column F of the table of data. And then output in a new table all of the rows which match that specific date (Data!Q27 changes, but is always in the MMM-YYYY format)

I created a similar solution for another table which worked, however for this data table it is not working. The working solution is shown below:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$K$7523,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$A$1:$A$7523,7)=Data!$Q$25,ROW(Data!$A$1:$K$7523)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Data!$A$1:$K$7523,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$A$1:$A$7523,7)=Data!$Q$25,ROW(Data!$A$1:$K$7523)),ROW(1:1)),1))`

*(This differs slightly as the date format in the table and Data!Q25 is /mmm/yy, but it successfully creates the new table which changes values dependent on the value in Data!Q25)*

The format of the date in column F is e.g 09-May-2017 and is classified as 'general' type.

I have used this formula, and I get no error or value on the cell that this code is on:

`{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430,8
)=Data!$Q$27,ROW(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Data!$A$8004:$F
$10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430,8)=Data!$Q$27,ROW(Data!$A$8004:$F$1
0430)),ROW(1:1)),1))}`

The formula is formatted as an array, and therefore I believe this code should work, returning the first A column value of a row which fits the criteria of having, for example: "***May-2017" in its F column. However it doesn't.

Unfortunately due to corporate protection I am unable to share the spreadsheet, but if the information supplied in this isn't clear enough I could supply a new excel sheet to show my example?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NpS0_Bsy8XuicrPl8oy5tAswEa9QZ9X2 <- here  is a spreadsheet that I have recreated to show the issue. The real spreadsheet is different, but this shows the purpose of my problem. Regardless of there being values which should be picked up on the tab names 'Data for normal user', no data is shown.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'd imagine one of the fields is formatted as Date so behind the scenes the value is stored differently than a string. Perhaps changing to a text field might help (rarely the case but worth a try)... Also rather than `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX()),"",INDEX())` for error handling, I'd advise `=IFERROR(INDEX(),"")` it's just neater and won't cause the formula to have to calculate twice.

Comment: If you try the above and have no luck, perhaps a direct date comparison might work better for you: `IF(AND(YEAR(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430)=YEAR(Data!$Q$27),MONTH(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430)=MONTH(Data!$Q$27))`

Comment: An example would be good.  But why not just use the `Advanced Filter`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NpS0_Bsy8XuicrPl8oy5tAswEa9QZ9X2 <- here is a spreadsheet that I have recreated to show the issue. The real spreadsheet is different, but this shows the purpose of my problem. Regardless of there being values which should be picked up on the tab names 'Data for normal user', no data is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct, however you haven't offset the rows.

Your `INDEX()` is starting at row 8 so this will be the first indexed row. `SMALL()` is building an array of the exact row numbers so row 8 in `SMALL()` is row 1 in the index, therefore no results are showing.

You simply need to update the `IF()` within `SMALL()` to handle this offset: (This formula has been updated to respond to formula dragging, i will include your original after)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(ConfidentialLiveData!A$8:A$14,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(ConfidentialLiveData!$F$8:$F$14,8)=ConfidentialLiveData!$C$2,ROW(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$A$14)-7),ROW(1:1))),"")`

Or

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$J$14,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(ConfidentialLiveData!$F$8:$F$14,8)=ConfidentialLiveData!$C$2,ROW(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$J$14)-7),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$J$14,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(ConfidentialLiveData!$F$8:$F$14,8)=ConfidentialLiveData!$C$2,ROW(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$J$14)-7),ROW(1:1)),1))`

A quick tip for error handling formulas is to use F9 when highlighting sections of your formula to show what that is calculating. For example i highlighted `IF(RIGHT(ConfidentialLiveData!$F$8:$F$14,8)=ConfidentialLiveData!$C$2,ROW(ConfidentialLiveData!$A$8:$J$14))` and saw that that calculated as `{8;FALSE;10;11;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}` so the match was being found just that the row numbers being returned were not what we were looking for.

**Update:**

So your formula is starting on row 8004, that row in the index is row 1. To get that row returned you need to take away 8003 from the 8109 to give you the 106th indexed row. A common way to do this is to take away the starting row and add 1 which in your original formula would be: `{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data‌​!$F$8004:$F$10430,8 )=Data!$Q$27,ROW(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430)-ROW(Data!$A$8004)+1)‌​,ROW(1:1)),1)),"",IN‌​DEX(Data!$A$8004:$F $10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430,8)=Data!$Q$27,RO‌​W(Data!$A$8004:$F$1 0430)-ROW(Data!$A$8004)+1),ROW(1:1)),1))}`

Comment: Thanks glitch doctor, this works for the example spreadsheet that I supplied; however in the real one the formatting of the table is different :( - And when attempting to do F9 on that portion of the formula, I get an error as the table is so big, making the formula exceed the formula character limit for that function.

So I reduced the reference range of the function and did F9 on the same portion of the formula, and when using Oct-2017 as the search criteria F9 replaces that section of the formula with:

Comment: `{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;8109;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}` - The correct row is row 8109, which it is picking up and yet doesn't give the row values, any ideas?

Comment: @PythonBen So your formula is starting on row 8004, that row in the index is row 1. To get that row returned you need to take away 8003 from the 8109 to give you the 106th indexed row. A common way to do this is to take away the starting row and add 1 which in your original formula would be: `{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430,8
)=Data!$Q$27,ROW(Data!$A$8004:$F$10430)-ROW(Data!$A$8004)+1),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Data!$A$8004:$F
$10430,SMALL(IF(RIGHT(Data!$F$8004:$F$10430,8)=Data!$Q$27,ROW(Data!$A$8004:$F$1
0430)-ROW(Data!$A$8004)+1),ROW(1:1)),1))}`